# Grasping force-closure node?‏

Tags: ros, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

good morning/evening/night

is anyone aware of the existence of a ros node to check wether a certain set
of grasping points is form/force-closure?

thx in advance.

Josep

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10455/grasping-force-closure-node?%E2%80%8F/) by [Josep Arnau Claret](https://answers.ros.org/users/774/josep-arnau-claret/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please note that everything below is still in very early stages of development / integration...

One option is to use the external simulator GraspIt to perform these computations for you. Graspit is well set up to do this, but the interfacing will be a bit tricky.

Assuming the diamondback ROS distro, you can get GraspIt and its ROS wrapper, either from source code (https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/graspit_simulator/tags/diamondback) or from debs (sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-graspit-simulator)

Once you have Graspit running, the graspit_interface node inside the stack provides an example for starting the simulator with a ROS node running inside it, so it can service ROS requests.

Most of the work will then consist of writing a ROS service that takes in a set of contacts and performs the desired computations. The ROS node running inside GraspIt will take those in, ask GraspIt to perform the force/form-closure computations and return the result. Getting GraspIt to do exactly what you want will be non-trivial, but should be doable.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2011-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3